# SQL Server IN clause within the boolean of IF statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, in-clause

I have a query to debug and it contains something I haven't seen. Here's the analogue query of my problem.

```
DECLARE @i AS INT
DECLARE @total AS INT
SET @total = 0
SET @i = 0

IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) IN (N'Wednesday') BEGIN
    SELECT @total = @total + 1
        SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT @i
```

My question is in this part: `IN (N'Wednesday')`. What is that `N` before the varchar `'Wednesday'`. I have no idea if it's a kind of keyword or something like that. This query is okay to be executed; there will be no error. On the other hand, it would be okay too (as far as I know) when I remove this `N`. What interests me the most is that, when I change it to be `n`, it yields error.

Comment: In SQL Server, it specified a national character set string -- one where the characters are more than 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

The `N` prefix means the following string literal is an `nvarchar` value rather than a `varchar` value.

In SQL Server, `nvarchar` and `nchar` values are stored using UTF-16 and this has problems with storing higher-plane Unicode characters - but they can be worked-around. Whereas the `varchar` and `char` values use the server's configured default encoding (ISO 8859-1) which 
SQL Server calls "`iso_1`".

(I note that since SQL Server 2019, [SQL Server now *finally* supports](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928) UTF-8, which renders `nvarchar` obsolete in my opinion - as the only advantage UTF-16 has over UTF-8 is more efficient storage of code-points in the range 2048-65535 (where it uses 2 bytes whereas UTF-8 uses 3 bytes), but this is moot as most characters used by most languages are either within the 0-2047 range - so in the vast majority of cases for most applications, *especially* those processing predominantly Latin-based alphabets it's better to stick with UTF-8).

> This query is okay to be executed; there will be no error. On the other hand, it would be okay too (as far as I know) when I remove this N. What interests me the most is that, when I change it to be n, it yields error.

It errors because `DATENAME` returns an `nvarchar` value, not a `varchar` value, and you can't use the `IN` operator to compare `nvarchar` and `varchar` values together (but you can use the `=` operator) - or

Keep the `N''` syntax. Even if the `IN` operator did support mixing `varchar` and `nvarchar` operands, it means you avoid having to force SQL Server to convert values between `varchar` and `nvarchar`'s encoding - it also means that `DATENAME` will work in non-Latin contexts where "Wednesday" is not the name for hump-day.